# swift 3 how to subclass NSDate or Date

Tags: swift3

I'm trying to add a special `JSONSerializable` method to a `dateTaken` field so I wanted to extend `Date`. but I discovered that `Date` is a struct and cannot be extended, so `NSDate`. but I can't figure out how to get a `DateTaken` from a `Date`

```
class DateTaken : NSDate, JSONRepresentable {
    static var formatter = DateFormatter()

    var JSONRepresentation: AnyObject {
        DateTaken.formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"  // ISO8601
        DateTaken.formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC") as TimeZone!
        return DateTaken.formatter.string(from:self as Date) as AnyObject
    }
    var JSONLocalTimeRepresentation: AnyObject {
        DateTaken.formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        return DateTaken.formatter.string(from:self as Date) as AnyObject
    }
}

let d = Date()
let dateTaken : DateTaken = DateTaken.init(timeInterval: 0, since: d)
// exception



(lldb) p NSDate.init(timeInterval: 0, since: dateTaken)
(NSDate) $R0 = 0x0000000156e6fdb0 2014-10-13 08:49:18 UTC
(lldb) p dateTaken.init(timeInterval: 0, since: dateTaken)
error: <EXPR>:3:1: error: 'init' is a member of the type; use 'type(of: ...)' to initialize a new object of the same dynamic type
dateTaken.init(timeInterval: 0, since: dateTaken)
^
          type(of:  )
```

Comment: "Date is a struct and cannot be extended" What?? Extend is not at all the same as subclass.

Comment: Structs (like `Date`) can't be extended, but classes like `NSDate` can. In either case though, you shouldn't. Use an extension.

Comment: Sorry. I'm coming from JS. I want to test if a value is an `instanceof` DateTaken, and if so I wand to serialize it differently. I do not want to serialize all Dates the same way. How do I use `extensions` to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't Java. We have extensions for this.

```
extension NSDate: JSONRepresentable {
    static var formatter = DateFormatter()

    var JSONRepresentation: AnyObject {
        DateTaken.formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"  // ISO8601
        DateTaken.formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        return DateTaken.formatter.string(from: self as Date) as AnyObject
    }

    var JSONLocalTimeRepresentation: AnyObject {
        DateTaken.formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        return DateTaken.formatter.string(from: self as Date) as AnyObject
    }
}
```

I also suspect there's a bug in this caused by the sharing of `formatter`. After the `timeZone` is set for the first time in `JSONRepresentation`, `JSONLocalTimeRepresentation` will act like `JSONRepresentation`. I may be wrong, but I can't test it now. It's worth checking out.